# altering the print statement and getting rid of long decimal points

Tags: python

I have a print statement in my code which generates the following list. The line is,

```
grp = itertools.groupby(phonemeList, lambda i: i[1] is None)
phList = [tuple(i[1]) for i in grp if not i[0]] 

print "\nsyllable groups separated"
print '\n\n'.join(str(l) for l in phList)
```

The output is,

```
syllable groups separated
(('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0],  [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('s', [(0.0, 0.5), [0.10000000000000001, 1.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('aa', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('m', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [1.0, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]), ('ih', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], [0.10000000000000001, 0.5], [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('k', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('l', [(0.0, 0.69999999999999996), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.40000000000000002], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('eh', [(0.0, 0.40000000000000002), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('k', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('t', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.40000000000000002], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('aa', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('n', [(0.0, 0.40000000000000002), [0.10000000000000001, 1.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('ih', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], [0.10000000000000001, 0.5], [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('t', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.40000000000000002], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('g', [(0.0, 0.5), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('eh', [(0.0, 0.40000000000000002), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('l', [(0.0, 0.69999999999999996), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.40000000000000002], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('v', [[0.29999999999999999, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), (0.10000000000000001, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('ae', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('n', [(0.0, 0.40000000000000002), [0.10000000000000001, 1.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('ih', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], [0.10000000000000001, 0.5], [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('k', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('aa', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]),)

(('p', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [1.0, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]), ('l', [(0.0, 0.69999999999999996), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.40000000000000002], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('ao', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('iy', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], [0.10000000000000001, 1.0], [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('k', [(0.0, 0.29999999999999999), [0.10000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.80000000000000004], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), ('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))
```

Here the groups are separated with an outer round brackets(). But even inside the groups there are more than one alphabets. How do I get them each in a new line? I would also like to get rid of all these decimal places. The output should display only upto 1 decimal point. Though the input has only 1 decimal point but python just displays long decimal points in the output. The output should look like this,

```
syllable groups separated
(('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('s', [(0.0, 0.5), [0.1, 1.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('aa', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('m', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [1.0, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]), 
 ('ih', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], [0.1, 0.5], [0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('k', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('l', [(0.0, 0.7), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.4], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('eh', [(0.0, 0.4), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('k', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('t', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.4], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('aa', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('n', [(0.0, 0.4), [0.1, 1.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('ih', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], [0.1, 0.5], [0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('t', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.4], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('g', [(0.0, 0.5), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('eh', [(0.0, 0.4), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('l', [(0.0, 0.7), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.4], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('v', [[0.3, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), (0.1, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('ae', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], [0.1, 0.8], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('n', [(0.0, 0.4), [0.1, 1.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('ih', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], [0.1, 0.5], [0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('k', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))

(('aa', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]),)

(('p', [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [1.0, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]), 
 ('l', [(0.0, 0.7), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.4], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('ao', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0], (0.0, 0.5), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('iy', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], [0.1, 1.0], [0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('k', [(0.0, 0.3), [0.1, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.8], (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]), 
 ('pau', [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]))
```

Comment: So you mean that `print phlist` is giving you this output, and you want a replacement for that?

Answer (score 2):

Use format strings.

```
>>> print "%.1f" % 1.234
1.2
```

Comment: Well, he might need to fiddle around with something like `map(lambda tuple:"(%.2, %.2)" % tuple, tupleList)` and again apply this to each list - nothing too scary or special here. The key question I guess was how to control the decimal precision.

Comment: I can change the same print command to display the list of each alphabet in a newline. Then I can have a for loop which says to display upto 1 decimal point only.

Comment: Replace the `str(l)` with a formatting function like the map-lambda-combination I gave above. As for the decimal points, format strings are the nicest way of doing this IMHO.